# How to display MsgBoxes for Average Calculator

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to have the error messages displayed if the user doesn't insert any numbers, types in letters or symbols, and if they type in a number not in between 1-100. The GUI works fine if you add in the values, but trying to trigger the messages it crashes the GUI.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnCalcaulate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcaulate.Click

    Dim int_grade1 As Integer = TxtboxNum1.Text
    Dim int_grade2 As Integer = txtBoxNum2.Text
    Dim int_grade3 As Integer = txtBoxNum3.Text

    Dim int_avgGrade As Integer = (int_grade1 + int_grade2 + int_grade3) / 3

    lblAverageNum.Text = int_avgGrade




    If (TxtboxNum1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Value for Number 1")
        TxtboxNum1.Focus()
        LblNumber1.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtboxNum1.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox("Number 1 value must be a number")
        TxtboxNum1.Focus()
        LblNumber1.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf TxtboxNum1.Text > 100 Or TxtboxNum1.Text < -1 Then
        MsgBox("Number 1 value must be between 1-100")
        TxtboxNum1.Focus()
        LblNumber1.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf (txtBoxNum2.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Value for Number 2")
        txtBoxNum2.Focus()
        lblNumber2.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf IsNumeric(txtBoxNum2.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox("Number 2 value must be a number")
        txtBoxNum2.Focus()

    ElseIf txtBoxNum2.Text > 100 Or txtBoxNum2.Text < -1 Then
        MsgBox("Number 2 value must be between 1-100")
        txtBoxNum2.Focus()
        lblNumber2.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf (txtBoxNum3.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Value for Number 3")
        txtBoxNum3.Focus()
        lblNumber3.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf IsNumeric(txtBoxNum3.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox("Number 3 value must be a number")
        txtBoxNum3.Focus()

    ElseIf txtBoxNum3.Text > 100 Or txtBoxNum3.Text < -1 Then
        MsgBox("Number 3 value must be between 1-100")
        txtBoxNum3.Focus()
        lblNumber3.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf lblAverageNum.Text >= 60 Then
        lblAverageNum.ForeColor = Color.Green

    ElseIf lblAverageNum.Text < 60 Then
        lblAverageNum.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Else
        int_grade1 = CInt(TxtboxNum1.Text)
        int_grade2 = CInt(txtBoxNum2.Text)
        int_grade3 = CInt(txtBoxNum3.Text)
        int_avgGrade = CInt(lblAverageNum.Text)




    End If
End Sub
```

While the calculations worked, when I try to activate the error messages for (blank space, input of letters or non-numbers, or number not between (0-100)) But it crashes my program and instead displays an error in my program saying "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: That this compiles: `Dim int_grade1 As Integer = TxtboxNum1.Text` tells me you are **NOT** using `Option Strict`, and that is not good. Turn on Option Strict, fix the compiler errors it causes, and then see if things make more sense.

Comment: If you want to do validation, there's already infrastructure in place to do it, so I would recommend to take that approach instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Also: I would strongly recommend to use `Integer.TryParse` instead of `IsNumeric`.

Comment: You need to debug your code. You need to do that before posting here. If you don't know how to debug, you should stop what you're doing and learn that first.

Answer (score 1):

The program crashes because the code at the top of the method attempts to do the calculations (and data type conversions) *before* completing the validation, meaning it can attempt to convert invalid values.

To fix it, don't do the calculation or assign your integer variables until *after* the validation steps, preferably using `Integer.Parse()`, and then *only if validation succeeds.*

Additionally, you should abstract the validation into a method, to avoid repeating so much code, and you should *definitely* turn on `Option Strict`.

Comment: So.. I tried that, but then it labelled

ElseIf lblAverage.Num.Text >= 60 Then as an error 

But instead conversion from string "Average Grade" to type "Double" is not valid. I never set it as a Double data type

Comment: @ColinMcDonald Values have data types, whether you set them or not. That's why you use Option Strict. It forces you to be more aware of the types in actual use, so you can avoid this kind of thing ahead of time, rather than delivering code that might eventually blow up in front of the user.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is so obvious if you check the first few lines of the code. `The GUI works fine if you add in the values, but trying to trigger the messages it crashes the GUI.` This is exactly what is causing the "crash"